# Trying to replace text but the string is unchanged

Tags: python, string, function

> Write a Python program to get a string from a given string where all occurrences of its first char have been changed to '$', except the first char itself

My code goes like this:

```
stringa = "restart" 

def swaping(palavra):
    prim = palavra[0] 
    for i in palavra:
        if prim in palavra and prim not in palavra[0]:
            palavra.replace(prim, "$") 
    return palavra 

print(swaping(stringa))
```

It should have returned `resta$t`, but it returned the same form, `restart`.

Does anyone have an idea why it won't work? The sample solution is completely different from mine, they chose to split the string in two and bind them together in the end.

Comment: Instead of looping, you could try `return prim + palavra[1:].replace(prim, '$')`

Comment: In addition to the other answers, the `.replace()` function does not modify the existing string; it returns a _new_ modified string, but you aren't saving this result.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your string stayed the same is because the `if` statement always returns False:

- `prim in palavra` is always True because `prim` is the first character in the string `palavra`.
- `prim not in palavra[0]` is always False because `prim` *is* `palavra[0]`, thus it is always in itself.

Combining them with an `and` clause and you'll get a False every time.

Also, `str.replace` will replace every occurence it finds (most of the times). There's no way to replace a character at a particular index in Python but to slice that string in half and do what your solution does.

Regardless, there's a simpler solution using `str.replace`:

```py
def swapping(string):
    return string[0] + string[1:].replace(string[0], '$')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple `replace()`, like this:

```py
string = 'restart'
new_str = string.replace('r', '$').replace('$', 'r', 1)
new_str
```

Output:
'resta$t'

Answer (score 0):

In your code as I can see it never be go into the `if` loop because `prim not in palavra[0]` gives always `False` as we assign `prim = palavra[0]`, so your 'string' is not changed.
I suggest to use below code:

```
stringa = "restart" 

def swaping(palavra):
    prim = palavra[0] 
    palavra = ''.join([prim,palavra[1:].replace(prim,'$')])
    return palavra 

print(swaping(stringa))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate through the string and match the occurrence of the first character with each element if matched then add `$` in the resultant string else add the same character in the resultant string and return that resultant string

```
def func(string):
    if len(string)<2:
        return string
    first = string[0]
    result = first
    for i, v in enumerate(string[1:]):
        if v==first:
            result+='$'
        else:
            result+=v
    return result

result = func('restart')
print(result)
```

output

```
resta$t
```